# How can my process of modeling be Sped Up?

Tags: modeling, interface, workflow

I noticed that it takes me **too much** time modeling some simple things, I can't understand why it is so.

I am using Blender for quite a long time already and using all the Hotkeys possible, but still I think I'm not efficient enough.

I would like to know if there is a way to 3D Model Faster / More Efficiently, Apart from being an experienced user and knowing where every function/button is or using Hotkeys.

Comment: I find that the more time spent on planning, the easier the execution.  But the answer in my opinion really is: Practice, Practice, Practice...

Comment: If you could tell the specific things that take you time, we could work out ways to speed it up.

Comment: Michelangelo complained about the time required to paint the Sistine Chapel so you are in good company. Quality not quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic bullet. The only real way to get faster, is to practice and learn about the different tools available to you (watch tutorials).

As you practice, you start to notice things that you do a lot, and eventually you might find a tool that can achieve a task faster. Tutorials help speed up the process, but they only show what the tools can do, not how you should use them.

You also might find that you work faster with a certain tool than other people. Essentially, some people work well one way (and that's what they'll teach), and others work better other ways.

Lot's of things can be taught in tutorials, but you can only learn to do those tasks quickly as you become comfortable with them. The only way to become comfortable with them is experience.